# R Programming Ignore Case Sensitivity when reading from Excel Files

Tags: r

I have a line that basically reads an excel file:

```
MyData <- read_excel("C:/Folder/MySpreadsheet.xlsx", sheet = "Get_Data", skip = 2)
```

However R is case sensitive, so when the sheet name is written like "GET_DATA", it produces an error that sheet is not found.

The sheet is not always in the same location all the time, and this line of code is inside a loop looking at hundreds of spreadsheets.

Is there a way for R to read the sheet ignoring case sensitivity?

Would the functions toupper() or tolower()  work and how would it look written? Thanks.

Comment: If the sheet position is the same, you can pass an index i.e. `sheet = 1`

Comment: It's actually not always in the same location :( .

Answer (score 3):

As we are using `readxl`, using the `excel_sheets` will be an option to return all the sheets, find the name corresponding to 'Get_Data' with case ignored (`ignore.case = TRUE`), and use that in reading

```
library(readxl)
nm <- grep("Get_Data", excel_sheets("C:/Folder/MySpreadsheet.xlsx"), 
          ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
MyData <- read_excel("C:/Folder/MySpreadsheet.xlsx", sheet = nm, skip = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Import relevant libraries: 
library(readxl)

# Store a variable denoting the path to the file: 
# spreadsheet_file_path => character scalar
spreadsheet_file_path <- "C:/Folder/MySpreadsheet.xlsx"

# Store a vector of sheet names: 
# sheet_names => character vector
sheet_names <- excel_sheets(spreadsheet_file_path)

# Find the relevant sheetname regardless of case: 
# import_sheet_name => character vector
import_sheet_name <- grep(
  "get_data", 
  sheet_names, 
  ignore.case = TRUE, 
  value = TRUE
)

# Read in the data: MyData => data.frame
MyData <- read_excel(
  spreadsheet_file_path, 
  sheets = import_sheet_name,
  skip = 2
)
```

Comment: Appreicate it thanks ill try it out